# How can I extract multiple zip files and read those csvs in R?

Tags: r, zip

I need to unzip multiple files at once and add it as a data frame in my R dashboard.

I'm currently using this code:

```
zipF<- "/Users/sahilverma13/Desktop/chat_data_2017-01-30_IST.zip"
outDir<-"/Users/sahilverma13/Desktop"
unzip(zipF,exdir=outDir)
```

But I have to do it for every file separately.

```
zipF <- list.files(pattern="*.zip")
```

I tried using the wildcard but it doesn't work.

Please help.

Comment: try this `zipF <- list.files(pattern=".zip", full.names = T)`; `sapply(zipF, unzip, exdir = ...)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I often use the ldply function from the plyr package to read or do stuff with multiple files.

```
library(plyr)

# get all the zip files
zipF <- list.files(path = "/your/path/here/", pattern = "*.zip", full.names = TRUE)

# unzip all your files
ldply(.data = zipF, .fun = unzip, exdir = outDir)
```

As Richard pointed out this is not complete (to much coffee in the morning is also not good).

```
# get the csv files
csv_files <- list.files(path = outDir, pattern = "*.csv")

# read the csv files
my_data <- ldply(.data = csv_files, .fun = read.csv)
```

I liked the comment of Joel a lot. I'am used to using the plyr package so much that I forgot that you can also use the sapply function. Maybe even better to use!

Comment: This is half the problem, but does not read the csv files into R

Comment: This works perfectly, Thanks! 
Except just one line

# read the csv files
my_data <- ldply(.data = csv_files, .fun = read.csv)

This line doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Just to check, but : Have you installed the `plyr` library? and The `# read the csv files` is a commented line. Do you get any errors?

Comment: In the list.files, you may want to add `full.names = TRUE` if your files are not in the working directory.

Comment: In the list.files, alternatively, you can use `recursive = TRUE` to get all files in one directory and its sub-directory with full names

Comment: On the unzip command, you can also use base R: `lapply(zipF, unzip, exdir = outDir)`. ldply` can throw errors in certain instances.